# Ursina Co-ordinate system - not working with large x,y,x values

Tags: ursina

I am trying to give position as (-11176.87,87646,987654) this is not shown in the ursina UI. I am working on realtime orbit simulation. How to customize the Ursina UI with any coordinate values?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
camera.clip_plane_far = [some arbitrary large number]
```

However, for distances larger than roughly 1,000,000 (I tested 10,000,000) other rendering issues appear. I think I search for a better engine...